# How can i append current date in text file name?

Tags: batch-file, filenames

I have a text file that is created at run time by batch script. how can i append the current date in the text file name like `instancename_4/12/2013` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
echo off
set v = instancename_%date%.log
echo some log >> %v%
```

Answer (score 2):

Use following

```
set filea=MyBigFile%date:~10%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set filename=instancename_%date:/=_%.txt
```

should set the filename close to your specification.

You can't have `/` in a filename. The `%date:/=_%` converts `/` to `_`.

Since your date format appears to have a suppressed leading zero, attempting to use substringing won't work properly.

We'd really need to know precisely how the variable `%date%` appears on your machine. It may have the dayname and some people have the monthname spelled out rather than numeric. Some people also have suppressed-leading-zero n the month as well - and I believe it's also possible to have the day or month with a leading space for (day, month)<10 And the year may have 2 or 4 digits, too.

It may also be possible to use

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3delims=/" %%a in (%date%) do set filename=instancename_%%a_%%b_%%c.txt
```

again, `_` being substituted for `/`.

The power of this format is that you could also reverse the sequence of %%a..%%c to give you the date in YY_MM_DD format which is better for sorting. YMMV.